# 502 Bad Gateway upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream with flask, uWSGI, nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

how are you?
I have a server on DigitalOcean with Ubuntu 16.04
I am making a Flask Application with uWSGI and Nginx.

My files look like:
wsgi.py:

```
from flaskapp import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

flaskapp.ini

```
[uwsgi]
limit-as = 512
module = wsgi:app
plugin = python
master = true
processes = 5
socket = flaskapp.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

/etc/systemd/system/flaskapp.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve flaskapp
After=network.target

[Service]
User=blitwak
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/blitwak/flaskapp
Environment="PATH=/home/blitwak/flaskapp/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/blitwak/flaskapp/myprojectenv/bin/uwsgi --ini flaskapp.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/flaskapp.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 162.243.76.55;

    charset utf-8;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 1k;
    proxy_buffers 24 4k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 8k;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 2048m;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 32k;

    proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;


    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///home/blitwak/flaskapp/flaskapp.sock;

 uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT app.wsgi;

          uwsgi_buffer_size 32k;
          uwsgi_buffers 8 32k;
          uwsgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;


   }
}
```

and in /var/log/nginx/error.log it says a lot of times:

> 2017/01/19 15:58:18 [error] 19181#19181: *36 upstream prematurely
>   closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   {myip}, server: {myserver}, request: "POST /yajugue HTTP/1.1",
>   upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/blitwak/flaskapp/flaskapp.sock:",
>   host: "{myserver}", referrer: "http://{myserver}/jugarPrimeraVez"

Thank you very much!!!

How can I resolve it?

Comment: The uwsgi seems to be timing out or something and closing the connection early. I also notice you have a bunch of proxy_ directives which won't affect the uwsgi, you have to use the appropriate uwsgi_ directives.

Comment: But why uwsgi makes a time out? I can delete that proxy_directives

Comment: Uwsgi is not timing out. The upstream server is closing the connection prematurely

Comment: I don-t understand. nginx is closing it? How I can resolve it?

Comment: Flask is closing the connection, not NGINX. Is there any errors in the flask log?

Comment: Where I can see them? In /var/log I don-t find a folder with name flask

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't used flask. Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982411/how-to-enable-uwsgi-logging-to-a-file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe enough set rule for Flask app.
For example:

```
sudo chmod 710 /var/www/flask_app 
sudo chown -R nginx: /var/www/flask_app
```